# Does cytoplasmic streaming cause passive organelle movement in animal or fungi cells?

Tags: organelle, cytoskeleton, intracellular-transport

In plant cels there is a current debate about whether or not cytoplasmic streaming, which is thought to be driven by the force of myosin motors transporting cargo along actin filaments, can cause organelles to move by passive advection.

I want to know if this is a genuine means of transport in other eukaryotic kingdoms, and not just passive movement of small molecules, but actual organelles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that fungi use cytoplasmic streaming to transport organelles to the tips of their hyphae to extend them. I haven't heard of cytoplasmic streaming in animal cells but it might exist.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melanosome
you will see an example of this organelle being transported in animal cells.

Is this what you mean? or are you looking for unbound organelles being swept along by a current?

Comment: Thank you for answering, and yes I mean unbound organelles.